# Calling Python script in excel as executable

Tags: python, excel, vba, shell, exe

I am currently developing a tool for a client that interfaces with both python 2.7 and excel 2013 and as a result running into a problem.

As background, I have a python code I want to run as a executable. The client doesn't have python on their computers so it's vital that the exe runs without .py. I've converted the script from a .py to a .exe with py2exe. Then I am trying to call that .exe with VBA. When the macro runs it looks like it pulls up the command prompt for a second but it doesn't run the .exe. When I go into the directory and double click the .exe however, it runs fine and outputs what I want it to.

Below is my code in VBA:

```
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
ChDir folderPath

Dim stAppName As String
stAppName = folderPath & "\dist\MAT.exe"
Call Shell(stAppName, 1)
```

Not sure if my Shell needs any other inputs

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does your script make any assumptions about the current working directory, like it only runs if the working directory is the same as the script directory?

Comment: Are you able to launch other executables, e.g. `notepad.exe`, using `Shell()`?

Comment: to furthure abarnerts comment... you should try opening a command window to a directory outside of your `folderPath` and launch your program with the fully qualified path... you almost certainly have an error traceback

Comment: Also, how do you know it doesn't run the exe? (What's the visible difference between that and, say, it runs the exe, which immediately quits because it doesn't find anything to work on, or it runs the exe, which raises an unhandled exception because of permissions errors and dumps a traceback that you don't get to see before the window closes, etc.?)

Comment: One more thing: Is that `folderPath & "\dist\MAT.exe"` actually the right path to the program? Is the `dist` directory guaranteed to be in the same directory as the .xls file?

Comment: It does not make any assumptions on the current directory to my kowledge. I can launch other executable using shell which is the weird thing

Comment: abarnert i know it doesn't run the exe because the python script is set to output a few different csv in another folder which it does when i double click the executable but not when i use the macro to call it. the \dist\MAT.exe will always be there. I can launch other executables from that folder too just not the .exe python script

Answer (score -1):

this is an indirect answer more to help you figure out what might be wrong

in your main file put your program in a `main` function (you dont *have* to call it main... you can call it whatever)

```
def main():
   #do whatever
```

then when you run it if its main do this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
       main()
    finally:
       raw_input("Hit enter To Close...")
```

this will guarantee your window to stay open even if there is an uncaught error